# Image is not setting in ImageView with setImageURI()

Tags: android, uri, android-imageview, android-image

Create own camera as I'need Focus ON for taking picture. Camera works perfectly fine as expected. Passing `URI` between activities.

I've <kbd>ImageView</kbd> in Next Screen which i used to set the Image with

```
imgView.setImageURI(absPathUri);
```

Checked that `absPathUri` is not null. Still <kbd>ImagView</kbd> is blank with no pictures. Doing the same in debug mode brings the Picture in <kbd>ImageView</kbd>.

#### *Can anybody please tell where I'm doing wrong?*

Also send broadcast to re-scan the device but still no success with following snippet.

```
 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
 File f = new File(absPathUri.getPath());
 Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
 mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
 this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Uses Below snippet to generate `absPathUri`

```
 if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
    {
        imageDirectory = new File(AppConstants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    }
    else
    {
        imageDirectory = new File(AppConstants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH_DATA);
    }

    imageDirectory.mkdirs();
    File tempFile = new File(imageDirectory, getVideoName()+ jpg);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( tempFile );
    absPathUri = outputFileUri;


  public static String getVideoName()
{
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    try {
        name = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Below is the Layout which i used to show the ImageView in xml.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/accounts_glyph_password_default"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/buttonPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onDiscard"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:onClick="onSave"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me how you create the object absPathUri

Comment: @gnuanu : edited the OP what you asks for. But why it works in debug mode.

Comment: According to the documentation, reading large images using setImageURI is not recommended because all processing happens in UI thread (reading/decoding/rendering)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29

Comment: @gnuanu `Bitmap bm=null; bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absPathUri.getPath());
  imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);` did try these still no image is showing up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by gnuanu, `setImageURI()` is not better to use as reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup.

Better to use the following:-

`setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.`

Still these methods didn't solve my problem. As I was taking Picture with Camera and onClick of it sending to Next Activity which may cause latency hiccups.

So better to pass to another activity after some peroid of time . .  just a  sec is totally convient to get through it.

Snippet which solve my issue:-

```
final Intent picIntent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,PicSaveActivity.class);
picIntent.putExtra("URI", pathUri.toString());
Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    startActivityForResult(picIntent, PICTAKEN);
    };
};
 Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
 handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
```

In Next Activity, catch the URI and rotate the Image as it would be in landscape mode.

```
 if(absPathUri!=null)
{
    Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absPathUri.getPath());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
    }
```

Comment: setImageBitmap() is deprecated and setImageUri() is not showing my image, can you help in this case, please.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [ImageView setImageBitmap not working on certain devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947624/imageview-setimagebitmap-not-working-on-certain-devices/27752064#27752064)
I found that in my case, I needed to call invalidate after setImageBitmap:

```
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imgView.invalidate();
```